# Join two result in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I started a new project with codeigniter and I create three tables for users and posts and likes like this

user table has these records

1. User_ID
2. FullName
3. UserName

post table has these records

1. Post_ID
2. Title
3. User_ID

that user_id field save creator user_id

and like table

1. Like_ID
2. User_ID
3. Post_ID

I want to join this three tables and I can do it but I need join two result like this and I don't know what can I do

```
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('Post');
  $this->db->join('User', 'User.User_ID = Post.User_ID', 'left');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
```

and this

```
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('Like');
  $this->db->where('User_ID' = $id);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
```

and then join these results with together

Please help me

Comment: What do you want exactly ? can you give dummy data to explain what you want to obtain please ?
You can do it with a single SQL query no ?

Comment: What data exactly you want ? and what are the fields to compare ?

Comment: I need join the first result with second result
or
I need select all post and I understand current user like which one post or not

Comment: @AmirNahravan can you elobarate with what you expect as answer. Example is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to determine which posts the current user likes. The sql statement would look like sg like the following:

```
select p.*, u.*, l.user_id as like_user_id
from post p
inner join user u on u.user_id=p.user_id    -- I do not think you need a left join here
left join `like` l on p.post_id=l.post_id and l.user_id=$id
```

I the `like` table is left joined to the `post` table using the common `post_id` fields. In case l.user_id is null, then the current user does not like the post. Based on the above query and your 1st codeigniter code, you should be able to create the codeigniter version of this query.

Answer (score 5):

You can join multiple tables in single codeigniter query

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('Post');
$this->db->join('User', 'User.User_ID = Post.User_ID', 'left');
$this->db->join('Like','Like.Post_ID = Post.Post_ID AND User.User_ID = $id','left');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```